# pkcs12 extract cert and key from pfx file

Tags: python-3.x, pkcs#12, python-cryptography

I'm trying to extract the cert and key from the pfx file, and then write them to the x.key and x.crt files.
I can get the cert and key by the below Python code, my question is how to write them to the file.

```
private_key, certificate, additional_certificates = pkcs12.load_key_and_certificates(pxfile.read(), None)
```

the certificate type is x509.Certificate, how can I convert it to string to write to the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get bytes via the blow code, then open file with "wb" to write.

```
certificate_bytes = certificate.public_bytes(Encoding.PEM)
private_key_bytes = private_key.private_bytes(Encoding.PEM, PrivateFormat.PKCS8, NoEncryption())
```